# Is there a duo tag or something like that

Tags: support, tags, search

Is there a way to search for duo campaigns- GM and player? Solo is pretty limited and seem to be no GM campaigns. Are there many duo threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [one-on-one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-on-one) tag, and there's also the [two player](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+player+is%3Aquestion) keyword, though that more often hits on a circumstance with one GM and two players.

You might also prefer [adventure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adventure) to [campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign) and its siblings.

Comment: Great answer, great support!

Comment: @C.Ross D'aw shucks, thanks.

Comment: Agree.  I have added a "duo" synonym to [tag:one-on-one] as well to help people poking around for a term.